# How to explicitly load more than one DbSet using one connection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am just starting to use EF6. I would like to know if it is possible to explictly load more than one DbSet of a DataContext using one connection?

Say for example I have a DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<EntityA> EntityASet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityB> EntityBSet { get; set; }
}
```

If I use the code:

```
var context = new MyContext("...");

context.EntityASet.Load();
context.EntityBSet.Load();
```

Each Load call opens and closes a connection, so 2 connections are opened and closed.

Is there a way to explicitly load both DbSets using one connection?

Comment: @Isma , not quite sure what you are asking?

Comment: After calling Load like that I can use Linq on the Local collection of each DbSet. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Isma , calling Load is the equivalent to calling .ToList and then throwing away the List without the overhead of actually creating the List. This is also mentioned in the tooltip of the Load method in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Isma , in my scenario I am happy to cache the entities up front with Load, but I am looking for the most efficient way to retrieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using the [`Database.Connection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Database.Connection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property to open the connection explicitly:

```
context.Database.Connection.Open();
try
{
    context.EntityASet.Load();
    context.EntityBSet.Load();
    // …
}
finally
{
    context.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

Another way is to open an explicit transaction:

```
using (context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    context.EntityASet.Load();
    context.EntityBSet.Load();
    // …
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Much appreciated. I wonder if you could help explain something else to do with this. I have been using '_context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine' to track database interaction. This has been useful for me to check the connections and queries. However, using your connection technique above, the log does not show the connection opening and closing. I wonder if you could explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that as well. May be they are logging connection open / close only when they do it implicitly as part of an EF initiated operation (so it has begin / end point).

Comment: You are welcome. Just realized that we can also use transaction, which gives us logging as well.

Comment: I like the Transaction approach. Brilliant stuff.